# Black Screen while Using Windowmanager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE in google pixel 6 (android >= 11)

Tags: react-native, screenshot, screen-capture, screen-recording, flag-secure

Black Screen while Using Windowmanager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE in google pixel 6 (android >= 11)

I face a black screen whenever I use Windowmanager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE to prevent screenshot and screen recordings on a device. This bug happens in specific devices like Google Pixel 6, Oppo, and Vivo.

The following app activates Windowmanager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE on clicking a button and then screen turns black.
The code is below: -

App.js: -

```
/* eslint-disable react/react-in-jsx-scope */
import {Button, StyleSheet, View} from 'react-native';
import * as ScreenCapture from 'expo-screen-capture';

export default function ScreenCaptureExample() {
  const activate = async () => {
    await ScreenCapture.preventScreenCaptureAsync();
  };

  const deactivate = async () => {
    await ScreenCapture.allowScreenCaptureAsync();
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <View>
        <Button title="Activate" onPress={activate} />
        <Button title="Deactivate" onPress={deactivate} />
      </View>
    </View>
  );
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    alignItems: 'center',
    justifyContent: 'center',
  },
});
```

ScreenCaptureAndroid.js: -

```
import * as ScreenCapture from 'expo-screen-capture';

const allowScreenCapture = async () => {
  try {
    await ScreenCapture.allowScreenCaptureAsync();
  } catch (e) {}
};
const disableScreenCapture = async () => {
  try {
    await ScreenCapture.preventScreenCaptureAsync();
  } catch (e) {}
};

const func = {
  allowScreenCapture,
  disableScreenCapture,
};
export default func;
```

ScreenCaptureModule.kt (File from expo-screen-capture node_modules folder): -

```
package expo.modules.screencapture

import android.view.Display

import android.content.Context
import android.view.WindowManager
import expo.modules.kotlin.exception.Exceptions
import expo.modules.kotlin.functions.Queues
import expo.modules.kotlin.modules.Module
import expo.modules.kotlin.modules.ModuleDefinition

class ScreenCaptureModule : Module() {
  private val context: Context
    get() = appContext.reactContext ?: throw Exceptions.AppContextLost()
  private val currentActivity
    get() = appContext.currentActivity ?: throw Exceptions.MissingActivity()

  override fun definition() = ModuleDefinition {
    Name("ExpoScreenCapture")

    OnCreate {
      ScreenshotEventEmitter(context, appContext.legacyModuleRegistry)
    }

    AsyncFunction("preventScreenCapture") {
      currentActivity.window.addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
    }.runOnQueue(Queues.MAIN)

    AsyncFunction("allowScreenCapture") {
      currentActivity.window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_SECURE)
    }.runOnQueue(Queues.MAIN)
  }
}
```